# VBA: Extracting the RGB value of lines in a chart with default colors

Tags: vba, excel, colors

### Problem

I would like to know how to read the current RGB value of an automatically assigned color in a chart, even if this entails freezing the colors to their current values (rather than updating them as the theme is changed, series are reordered, etc.)

### Usecase

My actual usecase is that I would like to make the datalabels match the color of the lines/markers in a line chart. This is easy if I have explicitly set the colors of the series via a scheme or explicit RGB values, e.g.

```
' assuming ColorFormat.Type = msoColorTypeRGB
s.DataLabels.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Fill.ForeColor.RGB= _
s.Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB
```

However, doing this when the series color is assigned automatically results in white labels. More specifically, both of the following equalities hold

```
s.Format.Line.ForeColor.Type = msoColorTypeRGB 
s.Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255,255,255)  ' White
```

And yet the line of course isn't white, but is an automatically assigned color from the theme. This shows that the color is automatically assigned

```
s.Border.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexAutomatic
```

I suppose it makes sense that the color isn't stored with the series in question. Even storing the index into the color scheme wouldn't generally work as Excel needs to change the color if another data series is added or someone reorders the data. Still, I would love it if there were some way to identify the current RGB value automatically.

### An Ugly Workaround

For charts with 6 or fewer entries, a simple workaround is to exploit the fact that theme colors are assigned sequentially, so I can do (e.g.)

```
chrt.SeriesCollection(1).DataLabels.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Fill.ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor _
= msoThemeColorAccent1
```

Presumably this could be extended to account for the `TintAndShade` used to differentiate entries once the theme has been exhausted, but this is such an ugly hack.

### Research

Someone asked essentially the same question (how to extract theme colors) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19395760/), but it was never answered. There are several sources suggesting ways to convert a known theme color into RGB values (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21142732) and [here](http://www.wordarticles.com/Articles/Colours/2007.php)) but that just begs the question; I don't know the color *a priori*, other than "whatever color this line currently is."

Comment: This is an excellent first question.  I seem to recall that *line* charts are particularly difficult to work with like this, having had some similar problems working with theme colors (and some non-theme colors) on charts in PPT.  I'll see if I have a function that can help you out...

Comment: Trying to debug, even if I **assign** `srs.Format.Line.ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorAccent2` and then attempt to query `?srs.Format.Line.ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor` gives me `0` (should be 6).  I get zero no matter what color is used.

Comment: See if the answer here can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21142732/how-to-get-the-rgb-long-values-from-powerpoint-color-palette

Comment: @DavidZemens Thank you for the suggestion (and the friendly feedback!). I actually linked to that answer at the end of my question; the problem is that I don't know which theme color (or variant thereof) to try to extract -- short of exploiting my knowledge that it cycles through the 6 palette colors with variations in brightness, which I would rather avoid.

Comment: Right. It is as if they made the ThemeColors deliberately difficult to work with.  I see an interesting observation, I will add it as an "answer" since it is too big to fit in the comments.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So this is interesting. I create a line chart using all defaults, and then I run this procedure:

[image]

```
Sub getLineCOlors()
Dim cht As Chart
Dim srs As Series
Dim colors As String
Dim pt As Point

Set cht = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Chart

For Each srs In cht.SeriesCollection
    With srs.Format.Line
    colors = colors & vbCrLf & srs.Name & " : " & _
            .ForeColor.RGB
    End With

Next

Debug.Print "Line Colors", colors

End Sub
```

The Immediate window then displays:

```
Line Colors   
Series1 : 16777215
Series2 : 16777215
Series3 : 16777215
```

But this is clearly not the case. It is obvious that they all are different colors.  If, instead of `.RGB` I do `.ObjectThemeColor`, then I get all `0`, which is equally and demonstrably false by observing the chart!

```
Line Colors   
Series1 : 0
Series2 : 0
Series3 : 0
```

**Now here is where it gets interesting:**

If, after having created the chart I *change* the series colors (or even leave them unchanged, by assigning to the same ThemeColors), then the function shows valid RGBs:

```
Line Colors   
Series1 : 5066944
Series2 : 12419407
Series3 : 5880731
```

It is as if Excel (and PowerPoint/etc.) are completely unable to recognize the *automatically assigned* colors, on Line Charts.  Once you assign a color, then it may be able to read the color.

**NOTE**: Line charts are picky, because you don't have a `.Fill`, but rather a `.Format.Line.ForeColor` (and `.BackColor`) and IIRC there are some other quirks, too, like you can select an individual *point* and change it's fill color, and then that affects the visual appearance of the preceding line segment, etc...

**Is this limited to line charts?**  Perhaps. My past experience says "probably", although I am not in a position to say that this is a bug, it certainly seems to be a bug.

If I run a similar procedure on a Column Chart -- again using only the default colors that are automatically assigned,

```
Sub getCOlumnColors()

Dim cht As Chart
Dim srs As Series
Dim colors As String
Dim pt As Point

Set cht = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(2).Chart

For Each srs In cht.SeriesCollection

    With srs.Format.Fill
    colors = colors & vbCrLf & srs.Name & " : " & _
            .ForeColor.RGB
    End With

Next

Debug.Print "Column Colors", colors

End Sub
```

Then I get what appear to be valid RGB values:

```
Column Colors 
Series1 : 12419407
Series2 : 5066944
Series3 : 5880731
```

HOWEVER: It still doesn't recognize a valid `ObjectThemeColor`. If I change `.RGB` then this outputs:

```
Column Colors 
Series1 : 0
Series2 : 0
Series3 : 0
```

So based on these observations, there is certainly some inability to access the `ObjectThemeColor` and/or `.RGB` property of *automatically-assigned* color formats.

As Tim Williams confirms, this was a bug as far back as 2005 at least as it pertains to the RGB, and probably that bug carried over in to Excel 2007+ with the ObjectThemeColor, etc... It is not likely to be resolved any time soon then, so we need a hack solution :)

**UPDATED SOLUTION**

Combine the two methods above!  Convert each series from line to `xlColumnClustered`, then query the color property from the `.Fill`, and then change the series chart type back to its original state.  This may be more reliable than trying to exploit the sequential indexing (which will not be reliable at all if the users have re-ordered the series, e.g., such that "Series1" is at index 3, etc.)

```
Sub getLineColors()
Dim cht As Chart
Dim chtType As Long
Dim srs As Series
Dim colors As String

Set cht = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Chart

For Each srs In cht.SeriesCollection
    chtType = srs.ChartType
    'Temporarily turn this in to a column chart:
    srs.ChartType = 51
    colors = colors & vbCrLf & srs.Name & " : " & _
            srs.Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB
    'reset the chart type to its original state:
    srs.ChartType = chtType
Next

Debug.Print "Line Colors", colors

End Sub
```

Comment: From almost ten years back: similar issue - http://www.office-archive.com/33-excel/57ab74e17cab9710.htm

Comment: Thanks Tim. If Peltier and Walkenbach say so then it's definitely a bug. Just hard to believe it could remain for a decade or longer!

Comment: This is a brilliant solution.  When I implemented this, the chart type changes to a template, and a second vertical axis on the right remains.  This can be remedied by changing the chart type (for the whole chart) back to Line at the end.

Comment: Great answer! I had to modify it to look at each point in my bar chart, since the bars are color coded by value. Unfortunately, they were set with themes, and I couldn't figure out the colors to make a matching legend. Now I've got them & I'll use the RGB values from this exercise to set everything.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the code I used in the end.

```
Sub ShowSeries()
Dim mySrs As Series
Dim myPts As Points
Dim chtType As Long
Dim colors As String

With ActiveSheet
    For Each mySrs In ActiveChart.SeriesCollection
        'Add label
        Set myPts = mySrs.Points
        myPts(myPts.Count).ApplyDataLabels ShowSeriesName:=True, ShowValue:=False

        'Color text label same as line color

        'if line has default color
        If mySrs.Border.ColorIndex = -4105 Then
            chtType = mySrs.ChartType
            'Temporarily turn this in to a column chart:
            mySrs.ChartType = 51
            mySrs.DataLabels.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = _
                mySrs.Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB
            'reset the chart type to its original state:
            mySrs.ChartType = chtType

        'if line has a color manually changed by user
        Else
            mySrs.DataLabels.Font.ColorIndex = mySrs.Border.ColorIndex
        End If
    Next
End With
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

After half a day I managed to solve this issue:

```
       Sub ......()

       Dim k as Integer
       Dim colorOfLine as Long

       ...............
       .................

       'Loop through each series
       For k = 1 To ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.Count

            With ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(k)

                .HasDataLabels = True

                'Put a fill on datalabels
                .DataLabels.Format.Fill.Solid

                'Get color of line of series
                colorOfLine = .Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB

                'Assign same color on Fill of datalabels of series
               .DataLabels.Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = colorOfLine

               'white fonts in datalabels
               .DataLabels.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)

            End With

        Next k
        ..........
        End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

the input which is used upon choosing colours are indeed not the R-G-B-values seperately, but seem to be rather predefined values given in the format "vbLong" or similar "long integer".

E.g.:
`ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate`

`RGBvalue =ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB`

`Debug.Print "RGB value = " & RGBvalue`

Similarly you can get the input value for specifying a colour by giving the RGB-values like this:
`RGBvalue = RGB(R, G, B)`

To change colour of lines you then give input either as 1) or 2)

`1) ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGBvalue`

`2) ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(R, G, B)`

Elsehow, if you want to get the RGB-values specifically, then there is code which does that here:

https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/vba/2014/11/5/retrieve-excel-cells-font-fill-rgb-color-code

The hex-code can also be gotten quite easily with the vba-function: `hex(RGBvalue)`